# Landau Vol. 2: On four-vectors

Tags: special-relativity, definition, classical-field-theory

In Chapter 1, section 6 of *The Classical Theory of Fields* by Landau and Liftshitz, I didn't understand the following:

*"Under purely spatial rotations (i.e. transformations not affecting the time axis) the three space components of the four-vector $A^i$ form a three-dimensional vector $\textbf A$. The time component of the four-vector is a three-dimensional scalar (with respect to these transformations)."*

What do they mean by a 'three dimensional scalar'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that it transforms trivially ($(A')^t=A^t$) under 3d rotations.  This does not mean that $A^t$ itself has three dimensions rather that it is a scalar from 3d point of view.

The direct analogy would be to consider 3d vector. You can decompose it to the 2d vector in the $xy$ plane and $a_z$. If you consider rotations in the $xy$ plane (i.e. around $z$ axis) $a_z$ does not change. We say that $a_z$ is 2d scalar.